# Setting custom bullet styles at different indent levels in Pages 5.0

Tags: pages, iwork

I am trying to set my bullets so that they are different at each of three indent levels in Pages 5.0. An example is like this:

[image]

I can accomplish this by manually changing the "Bullet:" tab on the format bar every time I indent:

[image]

As you can imagine, this is not an efficient way to work. I would like to create a setting/style where the bullets would automatically change when I hit "tab". I have attempted to update the "Bullet" style in the "Bullets & Lists" dropdown, but it can only set all of the indents to one bullet type.

Is there any way to change this so that whenever I hit "tab" my bullets change from:

> • --> ◦ --> -

This feature was available in Pages '09, but I cannot seem to find it in 5.0.

Comment: A vast number of 09 features have not yet been incorporated in 5.0. Normally the best fix is to go back to 09, which normally you should still have on your machine if you did not manually delete it.  And of course ask Apple via the feedback channel to bring 5.0 up to 09 capabilities.

Comment: Is the bullet customization feature now removed entirely from 5.1? All I can do is duplicate the preset styles — what a tease!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like Apple eventually added this feature to Pages 5. The following works for me in Pages version 5.2.2 (1877):

In case you've changed the style of any Bullet & List style, an asterisk (*) appears after the name of the style:

[image: IMAGE 1]

If you open the drop down list, you'll see an update button:

[image: IMAGE 2]

You can either press the update button, or click on the arrow next to it and select 'Update stlye' from the popup menu (featuring other options like clear, rename or delete):

[image: IMAGE 3]

Comment: It still works this way in Pages 8.2 in 2019! What a strange interface...

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are saving these files to a windows compatible format.  Apple periodically torpedos it's own software to force users to upgrade in frustration.  It seems to be a five year cycle.  What that means is you have major issues with preserving your data files.   Please be cautious about what file formats you use.  most open source software supports Windows formats.  Personally I feel file formats need to be locked to allow better cross platform compatibility.  Must like Europe requires vendors to use standardized power connectors for devices like phones.