# Pages 5: Increase indentation in table of contents?

Tags: macos, pages

Is it possible to have multiple indentations in the table of contents (auto-generated according to the paragraph styling)?

E.g.

```
•Header 1

....•Header 2

....•Header 2

........ •Header 3

....•Header 2

•Header 1
```

Sort of thing? I'm only able to get up to the second indentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disclosure: This is a different question from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/setting-custom-bullet-styles-at-different-indent-levels-in-pages-5-0?rq=1 . Mine is solely on the Table of Contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the indentation for each heading type in the TOC in Pages 5. Select a heading in the TOC then open up the Format Panel, go into the Text tab and change the Indents/First value (see pic). This updates the TOC's indentation for that type of header.

[image: changing outline]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know how I could define the order and layout of paragraph styles I added. Didn't find anything useful and Landed on this page. So I started to experiment and found it.

Go to the table of contents you generated, click on it. Click on the format inspector (the paintbrush). You can individually format every line, including indents. So put in whatever format/indent you like for a specific paragraph style and every other entry in that style will inherit that format.